# Euthyrodism and goitre

Tags: endocrinology, homeostasis

I read in [Tortora and Derrickson](http://bcs.wiley.com/he-bcs/Books%20?action=index&bcsId=6205&itemId=0470565101) that goitre is associated with [euthyrodism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euthyroid).

How is that possible?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but here is a fairly recent and highly-cited review that may be a good place to start: Krohn et al. (2005) Molecular pathogenesis of euthyroid and toxic multinodular goiter. Endocrine Reviews 26: 504-524

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context, euthyroidism refers to the amount of hormone present.

[What is a goiter](http://www.thyroid.org/what-is-a-goiter/):

> The term “goiter” simply refers to the abnormal enlargement of the thyroid gland. It is important to know that the presence of a goiter does not necessarily mean that the thyroid gland is malfunctioning. A goiter can occur in a gland that is producing too much hormone (hyperthyroidism), too little hormone (hypothyroidism), or the correct amount of hormone (euthyroidism). A goiter indicates there is a condition present which is causing the thyroid to grow abnormally.

See also [here](http://www.aerzteblatt.de/int/archive/article/127610) and [here](http://www.jfponline.com/fileadmin/php/qhi/qhi_redirect.php?article_id=5072) for more of the same info.

**ETA:** According to [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2804541/):

> Chronic lymphocytic thyroiditis (CLT), also known as Hashimoto thyroiditis, is an autoimmune, inflammatory process that causes up to 55% to 65% of all euthyroid goitres...

Although, as the link I already gave above state, regular ol' iodine deficiency can still cause euthyroid goiter.

Comment: What condition can cause an increase in size of thyroid gland but still produce normal amount of thyroxine ? (I specifically want to know this.)